# How can I change one list without changing the other?

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
 new_final_array=[x for x in new_array]
    for a in range(len(array)):
        for d in range(2):
            for l in range(len(new_array)):
                if new_array[l][d]==array[a][1]:
                    print l,d
                    new_final_array[l][d]=array[a][0]
```

I created list1(new_final_array) based on list2(new_array) and if I change one element on list1 it will also change on list2. How can I make them independent?

Comment: What is being stored in `array[a][0]`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 3):

Copy one level deeper.

```
new_final_array=[x[:] for x in new_array]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand, but maybe `copy.deepcopy` will be of some use.

```
import copy
new_list = copy.deepcopy(old_list)
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/copy.html).